# How to perform certain tasks when switching from/to Power Saver mode in Windows 8? (Disable services etc)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, automation, power-management

How can I disable certain services and terminate certain programs automaticly when I let my laptop go into power saver? And then automaticly restore them when I go to "performance" mode again?

If possible, can this be done without installing any additional software?

note: I am **not** talking about "when I switch from battery to AC or vice-versa"